# How can i pass url to play song with samsung s3 inbuilt music player?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-music-player

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.music","com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity");
intent.setComponent(comp);
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

This is the code that i am using to open samsung player in other phones except galaxy S3. Regarding  galaxy S3 this package is replaced with

```
ComponentName comp2 = new ComponentName("com.sec.android.app.music","com.sec.android.app.music.AudioPreview");
```

But in this case it is working only as audio preview but on pause it gets finished But i wanted play exactly like the one in the above as a music player . So for that i replaced ComponentName with this to open the musicplayer

```
 ComponentName comp2 = new ComponentName("com.sec.android.app.music",
                    "com.sec.android.app.music.MusicActionTabActivity");
```

But in the case the player won't plays the url that i have passed. It just open's the default music player in S3. I need to play file with the android default music player.

Comment: Why not just create an intent for audo/mp3 and let the user choose what app to launch it with?

Comment: In that case also when we select the  musicplayers from the phone only the AudioPreview option is enabled. And the song gets finished on pause. I need to push playing song to background

Comment: Unfortunately the android default music player may not be installed.  You can never assume a given app is.  Worse, different models of Samsung phones have different software layouts-  they all don't use the same music player.  Even S3 on different carriers may change out the music app, if for example Verizon has bought one and they want Samsung to use it. You're asking for a world of pain going down this route.  That's why intents filters based on MIME type were added.  You're going to end up having dozens of special arrays and add more over time.  I'd really suggest against it.

Comment: You are right.. but i just wanted to known if there is a way out there to en queue  my song with default music player and play via intent in background. Known i realize the hazards in making such type of implementation . Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look Android is using AudioPlaybackPreview or someother named activity, to handle the song playback from fileManager or any other place .

Actually you want to use the default Playing activity ,which is used to show all the controls and all .Dear it's not possible to use that Activity , since it had been linked to someother service having data of all the songs and all paths. This playing Activity has control of next atnd previous and all , that is linked with one playback service.

Third thing is that , as far as i know that **S3 is almost providing the same layout for playing the song from filemanager or for plaaying from any other activity**. But the problem with that is that when u go back from there , **it will stop the playing song**.

Refer to **android music player source code** , u will understand why it's not possible to launch that activity.